# ecmascript 6 type checks

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs

This compiles when I give it to babel

```
function foo(a: number, b: {prop: number}): number {
  return a + b.prop
}
```

However babel doesn't complain when I give it a string as an argument

```
foo('this', 'string')
```

Is this indeed valid ES6? If so, is the type information used somewhere?

Comment: This isn't valid ECMAScript 6, this is TypeScript.

Comment: so babel doesnt error on type declarations?

Answer (score 0):

Babel is just a JavaScript transpiler without any type checking. Maybe you're use a specific plugin for Babel?

I would recommend you to switch to [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) if you really need a complex type checking for your project. There will an explicit error for any typo in incorrect types usage.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this plugin for babel https://github.com/codemix/babel-plugin-typecheck  which uses Facebook's Flow http://flowtype.org/